# Proper order/place of subclass construction

Tags: c++, class, constructor

In some C++ code I have a class, let's call it masterClass, that contains as members several classes, subClassA, subClassB, and so on.

Where should I create the subClasses?  Should I construct and initialize them first, and then pass them to the masterClass?  Or should I construct and initialize them in the masterClass' constructor or inside of an initialization member function on the masterClass?

What is the best method, generally?

Comment: It really depends what you're trying to accomplish. If the constructors to subclasses are expensive, you should call them as late as possible and preferably not in masterClass's constructor. There are cases where you need to create an aggregated object and process it before sending it to parent class. Could you provide some code with examples of usage ? Unrelated, but useful: in most coding styles class names start with an uppercase letter.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the relationship between your masterClass and subClass is composition.

My suggestion is creating subClass and masterClass individually. And treat the instance of subClass as the member of masterClass. The same as what you said "construct and initialize them first, and then pass them to the masterClass". Since this is the correct usage of composition.

```
class subClassA {
    //...
};
class subClassB {
    //...
};
class masterClass {
    //...
private:
    subClassA subA;
    subClassB subB;
};
```